# Windows 10 unknown program

Tags: windows-10

There is a program that starts with the system as shown in the image below.

I do not know how to find out which program is this.

[image]

Comment: Right-click the column header, and enable [Command line](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/configure-task-manager-to-display-full-path-of-running-processes/). This tells you the full path / command-line used by that process.

Comment: use autoruns, it is much better: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx